# How to reformat string as int and repalce values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sqldatatypes

I am currently trying to pull in a field (NMBR) in SQL Server that has a datatype of char(5), which I would like to convert to int. However, some of the values in the field are not numbers, in which case I would like to assign a value in addition to converting to an int. I'm guessing I will need some combination of REPLACE functions, but not sure how to format the numbers properly.

Values from field I'm pulling from:

| NMBR |
| --- |
| NULL |
|  |
| . |
| 0 |
| 00 |
| 003 |
| 01 |
| 02 |
| TX |

One other piece to note about the values in the above is that there are random blank spaces before and after some of the values as well.

I would like to see the values like below:

| NMBR |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 0 |

So far I have come up with this: SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(COALESCE(NMBR, 0), ' ', 0), '.', 0) AS NMBR but I am getting a conversion error on the varchar to int. Also note that this would replace spaces with 0, so some of the values with extra spaces would then have extra 0's added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try_cast()` and `coalesce()` should be your friends here:

```
select nmbr, coalesce(try_cast(nmbr as int), 0) cast_nmbr 
from mytable
```

`try_cast` attempts to convert the strings to integers; it happily ignores trailing or leading spaces. When the conversion fails, the function returns `null`, which we can turn to `0`s using `coalesce()`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V660OU0S)**:

| nmbr | cast_nmbr |
| --- | --- |
| *null* | 0 |
| . | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 00 | 0 |
| 003 | 3 |
| 01 | 1 |
| 02 | 2 |
| TX | 0 |

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks so much! Can't believe I forgot about try_cast...